# redirect .htaccess file to work for another file in another directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

In my website i have two files `index.php` and `.htaccess`. Both are located in directory `public_html/image/public`. The `.htaccess` file plays a role that i do not have to mention `index.php` in URL. Here's the code of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

So `www.example.com/image/public/` points to `index.php`.
Now if i move `index.php` to `public_html` without moving `.htacces`s, how can i make the same functionality again as it was before(means not have to mention `index.php` in URL). I guess i have to make some changes in `.htaccess` file but i cannot seem to make it work out.

Comment: Is `public_html` not the server docroot anyway? That `.htaccess` file *should* be in the docroot, it's a standard routing script; the kind used by just about every MVC framework available in PHP.

Comment: Oh - and you should never have to mention `index.php` in the URL anyway, normal Apache directory indexing should deal with that - the `RewriteRule` there is to route *every* request that's not an existing file, or directory, to `index.php`. You'd do that with an MVC framework as `index.php` determines the relevant controllers and actions.

Answer (score 0):

Change `RewriteRule` line with this

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But if you just want to disable the listing of all images when someone hit the URL of an image path without imagename in your case it could be something like this  `www.example.com/image/public/`

You can do with this, just change all content of your `.htaccess` file with below code

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply . although i got an overview i would request to please elaborate a little if you can, just for my better understanding. thanks in advance